# How to split data of one column into multiple equal n columns in Excel or R?

Tags: r, excel

I have  along Column with 500 values. I want to split it in 5 columns with 100 values each.

```
Sample Input
1
2
3
4
...
50
```

Output:

```
Column 1
1...100
Column 2
101..200
column 3
201..300
column 4
301..400
column 5
401..500
```

Is there any way in Excel or R to make it easy? My file format is  a csv.

Comment: Try `matrix(df1[[1]], ncol = 5, nrow = 100)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROWS($1:1)+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*100)
```

and copy both downwards and across.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If your data starts in **A2** rather than **A1**, use this:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$99999,ROWS($1:1)+(COLUMNS($A:A)-1)*100)
```

Comment: ..I also want to assign headers. how i can do that?

Comment: @jsingh Very easy.............just place the original formula in **B2** rather than **B1** ..................this will leave the first row for any headers you wish to enter.

Comment: @jsingh  **My formula assumes that your input data starts in cell A1**

Comment: ..oh thats why its giving me  a zero. But my input data is starting at A2

Comment: @jsingh  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input data is in column `A`, and the output starts from column `B`, Try the following Macro. Assign it to a button for multiple uses.

```
Sub SplitInto100CellsPerColumn()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, vArrIn As Variant, vArrOut As Variant
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  vArrIn = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
  ReDim vArrOut(1 To 100, 1 To Int(LastRow / 100) + 1)
  For X = 0 To LastRow - 1
    vArrOut(1 + (X Mod 100), 1 + Int(X / 100)) = vArrIn(X + 1, 1)
  Next
  Range("B1").Resize(100, UBound(vArrOut, 2)) = vArrOut
End Sub
```